# My remote execution not able to read the config file from vault at run time

Tags: java, spring-boot, automated-tests, jenkins-pipeline, build-automation

So, for remote execution, due to my compamy's policy I store the db password and other configurations in a secret.txt file and we are storing that in vault server.

Now, in my CI pipeline I am giving the mount path of the secrets file and while exceution at run time and the build is failing with error:- Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /etc/config/secrets.txt (No such file or directory).

I tried changing the data of the secrets file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.